# Математические операции с датами (весь код уже внутри), переопределение диапазона выбора дат в datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, дата, jquery-ui, datepicker

В два поля изначально помещены даты: текущая и завтрашняя.

Это дата начала и дата окончания.

Задача состоит в том чтобы при выборе даты начала, дата окончания автоматически ставилась больше той, что стоит сейчас, при условии, что дата начала ставится больше даты окончания.

Например, если дата окончания выставлена 25 ноября, то при выборе даты начала 29 ноября, дата окончания автоматически вставилась на 1 день больше, но если дата начала выбрана меньше 25 то дата окончания оставалась той же, то есть 25 ноября.

с этим вроде бы справился, ну почти...

Не справился с тем, чтобы при любом выборе даты начала, диапазон выбора даты окончания становился уже (не ранее даты начала). Не хочет и всё датапикер принимать новые параметры...((

В функции `first()` и должна произойти магия
Ниже привел пример кода.

[тут его рабочая версия](https://jsfiddle.net/t0jbyqgq/1/)

```js
start = $('.start').val();
start_s = start.split('.');

day_start = parseInt(start_s[0]);
month_start = parseInt(start_s[1]);
year_start = parseInt(start_s[2]);

start_t = new Date(year_start, month_start - 1, day_start); //дата начала в timestamp
start_u = Date.parse(start_t); //дата начала в unix
start_year = new Date(start_u + 365 * 86400 * 1000); //ограничение выбора год


finish = $('.finish').val();
finish_s = finish.split('.');

day_finish = parseInt(finish_s[0]);
month_finish = parseInt(finish_s[1]);
year_finish = parseInt(finish_s[2]);

finish_t = new Date(year_finish, month_finish - 1, day_finish);
finish_u = Date.parse(finish_t);
finish_year = new Date(finish_u + 365 * 86400 * 1000);

$('.start').datepicker("setDate", start_t);
$('.start').datepicker({
  minDate: start_t,
  maxDate: start_year,
  setDate: start_t,
  onSelect: function() {
    flag = 0;
    first(flag);
  }
});

$('.finish').datepicker("setDate", finish_t);
$('.finish').datepicker({
  minDate: finish_t,
  maxDate: finish_year,
  setDate: finish_t,
  onSelect: function() {
    flag = 1;
    first(flag);
  }
});

//прошу не оптимизировать код функции мне бы понять сначала в таком развернутом виде, потом сам сверну
function first(flag) {
  start = $('.start').val();
  start_s = start.split('.');

  day_start = parseInt(start_s[0]);
  month_start = parseInt(start_s[1]);
  year_start = parseInt(start_s[2]);

  start_t = new Date(year_start, month_start - 1, day_start);
  start_u = Date.parse(start_t);

  finish = $('.finish').val();
  finish_s = finish.split('.');

  day_finish = parseInt(finish_s[0]);
  month_finish = parseInt(finish_s[1]);
  year_finish = parseInt(finish_s[2]);

  finish_t = new Date(year_finish, month_finish - 1, day_finish);
  finish_u = Date.parse(finish_t);

  console.log(start_u > finish_u);
  if (flag == 0) {
    if (start_u >= finish_u) {
      mod_finish_u = start_u + 86400 * 1000;
      mod_finish_t = new Date(mod_finish_u);
      //console.log(mod_finish_t);
      $('.finish').datepicker("setDate", mod_finish_t);
      $('.finish').datepicker({
        minDate: mod_finish_t
      });
    }
  } else if (flag == 1) {
    //еще не придумал))
  }
}

//переводчик
$.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
  closeText: 'Закрыть',
  prevText: '&#x3c;Пред',
  nextText: 'След&#x3e;',
  currentText: 'Сегодня',
  monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь',
    'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'
  ],
  monthNamesShort: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь',
    'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'
  ],
  dayNames: ['воскресенье', 'понедельник', 'вторник', 'среда', 'четверг', 'пятница', 'суббота'],
  dayNamesShort: ['вск', 'пнд', 'втр', 'срд', 'чтв', 'птн', 'сбт'],
  dayNamesMin: ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'],
  weekHeader: 'Нед',
  dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
  firstDay: 1,
  isRTL: false,
  showMonthAfterYear: false,
  yearSuffix: ''
};
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ru']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input class='start' type='text' readonly='true' value='05.11.2017'>
<input class='finish' type='text' readonly='true' value='06.11.2017'>
```

Буду буду благодарен, как за решение этой задачи, так и просто за ссылку на библиотеки, с календарями где можно заранее ограничить диапазон, и делать выбор начало-конец.
С кириллицей, и другими гибкими настройками

Comment: https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/

Comment: Есть модификация dateRangePicker, там кажется все это можно легко настроить и вполне приличная документация.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.finish').datepicker("option", { minDate:  mod_finish_t });
```

[вот тут работает](https://jsfiddle.net/t0jbyqgq/2/)